# Wasserstein-1 distance between two joint distributions

Tags: joint-distribution, wasserstein

Let me define random variables $A, B, C, D$ that are **independent** of each other. Additionally, PDFs of $A, B$ are the same, and PDFs of $C, D$ are the same too

In such a case, is the following correct?

> $$W^1(P_{A,B} \parallel P_{C,D})=2W^1(P_A \parallel P_C)$$

where $W^1$ means Wasserstein-1 divergence and $P_{A,B}$ is the joint distribution.

My observation is that
$$W^1(P_{A,B} \parallel P_{C,D})=\inf_{\pi \in \Pi(P_{A,B},P_{C,D})}E_{a,b,c,d\sim{\pi}}\|a-c\|_1+E_{a,b,c,d\sim{\pi}}\|b-d\|_1$$
Due to the above assumptions, it is equal to:
$$=\inf_{\phi \in \Pi(P_A, P_C)}2E_{a,c \sim{\phi}}\|a-c\|_1$$
$$=2W^1(P_A \parallel P_C)$$

where $\Pi(\cdot, \cdot)$ denotes all possible couplings between two distributions.

If anyone notices something wrong with the above expressions, could you let me know?

I also referred to Theorem 1 in [Joint Wasserstein Distribution Matching](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.00389.pdf).

Thank you

Comment: @Xi'an I added some expressions in the equations. Thank you :)